# Fixed right sidebar collapsing on responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a 2 column site: the left column is fluid and the right column is fixed. When I scale the browser in to check to see how the site responds the right column seems to collapse below the left column. I do not want this right column collapsing. I would like for the left main column to contract fluidly as the site is scaled in.

Here is the basics of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kGkRD/

```
<section class="main">
    Left
</section>

<aside class="sidebar">
    Right
</aside>

body {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section.main {
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
aside.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want it to display beneath the other one, what do you want it to do?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Should the larger one shrink and keep the sidebar width fixed, or do you want them both set to a fixed percentage (e.g. 70/30%) of their parent container, or what?  Wrapping sidebars beneath main content below a certain screen size is a very commonly used technique for responsive web design as you can imagine you don't really need a sidebar taking up a third of the screen on a 320px wide mobile portrait viewport.

Comment: The larger column (main) should shrink as the right column stays fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Put your right floated element first, remove the `float: left;` and `width: 100%;` from the `section.main` and add `overflow: hidden;`: http://jsfiddle.net/mdares/kGkRD/1/

**HTML:**

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    Hello World
</aside>
<section class="main">
    Hello World
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section.main {
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
aside.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Update:** Do I understand correctly and you are looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/mdares/kGkRD/4/

```
body {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section.main {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
aside.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If so you were just missing your `overflow: hidden;`

**UPDATE 2:** To address your comment try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mdares/kGkRD/5/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
section.main {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
}
aside.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    aside.sidebar {
    position: static;
    float: left;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <section class="main">
    Hello World
  </section>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    Hello World
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a media query let's say at 768 width, how would I go about stacking section.main ontop of aside.sidebar if the aside is stacked higher in the html order?

Comment: Updated - that that what you are after?

Comment: that's almost what I'm looking for, except the main column should remain flexible and the right column shouldn't break to the next line until instructed to do so by a media query.

Comment: Updated with `@Media` query that is doing what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    Hello World
</aside>
<section class="main">
    Hello World123
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width:500px){
section.main {
    //display:block;
    float:right;
}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGkRD/3/)

EDIT: Please use the updated css. try both using `display:block` and `float:right`.

Comment: this is what I would like to happen, except I plan on inserting a media query at 768 width and I want the sidebar to be placed on the bottom.

Comment: I'm just using 768 as an example as my site dimensions are much larger than what I have in the example fiddle.

Comment: ok.. now if you find my answer is correct then please mark it as answered. thank you

Comment: it's not completely correct as I want to the sidebar to stack beneath the main column. How do you make this happen?

Comment: you mean it should directly go below `.main` and not slowly as we go on decreasing resolution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38358/discussion-between-vishalkin-and-matt)